# Determining return type of std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm writing a template function that receives a `std::function` object (Generated by calling `std::bind` with the proper arguments).
Within this function, I would like to determine the return type of this function object. Is is possible?

As a matter of fact, I want the template function to return the same type. Can you think of an elegant, standard based, way of achieving this goal?

Something like:

```
template <typename T>
T::return_type functionObjWrapper(T functionObject) {
   // ...
   return functionObject();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `std::bind` does NOT return a `std::function`

Comment: No, but it does return a callable object, and that's sufficient to initialize a `std::function` with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using `decltype` and trailing return type:

```
template <typename T>
auto functionObjWrapper(T functionObject) -> decltype(functionObject()) {
   // ...
   return functionObject();
}
```

Comment: Only C++14 compatible!

Comment: @DavidHaim Works fine when I build using C++11 mode in GCC 4.7.2 (which doesn't have a C++14 mode). Also, trailing return types was part of the C++11 standard, as was `decltype`.

Comment: @DavidHaim This is plain old C++11. In C++14, you could drop the trailing return type completely

Comment: This implementation isn't reliable because calling functionObject()  just to obtain the return type can potentially modify static variables which may be unwanted.

Comment: @MosheRabaev `decltype` is a compile-time construct and works similar to `sizeof`. It doesn't evaluate the expression it is given, no function is actually called in `decltype(functionObject())`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanx, there's always something to learn everyday :)

Comment: Say I want to wrap a thread library and want to give similar interface as to `std::function`. To pack arguments and return type into a thread parameter struct, I need to know types given to me but since I lack C++11, I can't do `decltype`. Is there any other mechanism that lets me achieve this pre-C++11?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `std::function<F>::result_type`

I.e.

```
template <typename F>
typename std::function<F>::result_type
functionObjWrapper(std::function<F> functionObject) {
   // ...
   return functionObject();
}
```

The `typename` before `std::function<F>::result_type` is needed because that's a dependent type name.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class F>
std::result_of_t<F&()> functionObjWrapper(F functionObject) {
  // ...
  return functionObject();
}
```

`std::result_of` takes a type-expression that "looks like a function call".  It then tells you what would happen if you did a function call with that callable type, and those arguments.

If you lack C++14, replace `std::result_of_t<?>` with `typename std::result_of<?>::type`, or write your own:

```
template<class Sig>
using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;
```

In many C++11 implementations, `result_of` is even SFINAE friendly.

I do `F&()` instead of `F()` because we are going to use a non-const lvalue of type `F` to do the call.  If your last line was `std::move(functionObject)()` or `std::forward<F>(functionObject)()`, you would do `result_of_t<F()>`.

Comment: The use of result_of is very puzzling to me. It always results in something such as `invalid use of incomplete type struct std::result_of<main()::<lambda()>>`. I'm struggling to find a complete example where result_type would actually help filtering between return types for lambdas. What is "Sig" supposed to be in that example ? Apparently it cannot be the type of a lambda... but what should it be, then ?

Comment: @Michael It was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.  It should be `lambda_type()` not `lambda_type`.  They did a clever thing where they used a function type *returning* the lambda, and turned it into the return type of the lambda; sadly, function decay rules makes this a bad idea.  Use `invoke_result_t` instead.  If you need to know more, use the [ask a question] button (feel free to ping me here with a link to it, but others will probably answer first).