# Deduce the std::function result type and use it as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, functional-programming

This is how my simple class looks like.

```
template <class T>
class A {
T first;
T second;

public:
A(T f, T s) : first(f), second(s) {};

template <class F>
auto foo(F f) -> decltype(f(T(), T())) {
    return f(first, second);
}
};

int main() {
    A<int> a = A<int>(2, 3);
    a.foo([](int l, int r)->int{return l + r;});
}
```

I want foo to take a function (or lambda or fucntion pointer) f that takes two attributes of type T and return the result of f().

This code works, but I create dummy arguments to get result of decltype. In this case those are simple integers, but it can be anything, and I certainly don't want to construct dummy parameters from bigger classes. How to deal with that?

Moreover, this is just a simplified case. In my case foo looks like that:

```
foo(function f, result_type_of_f t1, result_type_of_f t2) {
    // do something
    return f(first, second, t1, t2);
}
```

I couldn't do it with methods similar to the first one, I also tried methods from this post [Determining return type of std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756392/determining-return-type-of-stdfunction) but to no avail.

Comment: `decltype` does not evaluate its operand, so nothing extra is constructed. There is the issue of a non-default-constructible `T`, which is covered by `std::declval`. But I don't understand how your "non-simplified case" would work.

Comment: Also, there is absolutely no `std::function` in your code -- a lambda is not a `std::function`.

Comment: Okay, maybe I simplified it a bit too much. In my case f takes 3 parametres, and I don't know the type of two of them, I only know that they are the same as return type, so I can't really use decltype, because I don't know what dummy class should I create in evaluation.

Comment: Do you need to handle overloaded functionoids? If so, where would you like to resolve ambiguities?

Comment: Okay, I came up with a good example - let's assume we have a binary tree and we want to traverse it, and get some result. So f takes three arguments : value from the node, value from left subtree and value from the right subtree. Values returned from subtrees can be of any type, but it needs to be the same as return type of f. Can it be deduced without adding new template parametres?

Comment: Assuming `f` is not overloaded, yes. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no overloaded functionoids to bother with, we can implement a `resultOf` type trait to retrieve the return type:

```
// std::void_t from C++17
template <class...>
struct voider {
    using type = void;
};

template <class... T>
using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

namespace detail_resultOf {

    // Base case, when it cannot be deduced
    template <class F, class = void_t<>>
    struct resultOf { };

    // Function object: grab its operator() and try again
    template <class F>
    struct resultOf<F, void_t<decltype(&F::operator())>>
    : resultOf<decltype(&F::operator())> { };

    // Member functions
    template <class Ret, class T, class... Args>
    struct resultOf<Ret (T::*)(Args...)> {
        using type = Ret;
    };

    // ...

    // Free functions

    template <class Ret, class... Args>
    struct resultOf<Ret (*)(Args...)> {
        using type = Ret;
    };

    // ...
}

// Public metafunction
template <class F>
using resultOf = typename detail_resultOf::resultOf<F>::type;
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fa1fe8111e520e0)

Then you can write your function as:

```
template <class F>
auto foo(F f, resultOf<F> t1, resultOf<F> t2) -> resultOf<F> {
    // do something
    return f(first, second, t1, t2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to create as complex of an argument to `decltype` as you want.

`decltype` is evaluated at compile-time, and results in no code being generated. The compiler will go through the motions of constructing all the arguments, in "dry-run" mode, figure out the resulting return type, and use it.

It is true that with complicated C++ code, all the work that the compiler has to do, due to `decltype`, templates, and other constructors, does slow down the compilation; but `decltype` eventually results in no run-time overhead, no matter what is `decltype`d.